Get category title with shortcode whithout a bullet list
i'd like to create a shortcode for wordpress to display the category name.
Each post on the website is associated with only one category, so there is no need to display a list of categories but only one category name.
I have found here this code :
function categories_list_func( $atts ){
 $categories = get_the_category();

     if($categories) {
        foreach($categories as $category) {
            $output .= '<li>'.$category->cat_name.'</li>';
        }
        $second_output = trim($output);
      }
      $return_string = '<ul>' . $second_output . '</ul>';

 return $return_string;

} // END Categories
add_shortcode( 'categories-list', 'categories_list_func' );

The code gives me a partial answer because the result shows a bullet before the category name. How to use the code without showing a bullet before the category name?
Correcting my question: what code is appropriate to show the category name?
The code in the example refers to a list, and this is appropriate for the case where a post is linked to more than one category. In my case there is only one category per post, so it is only necessary to display its name and not a list of names.

The bullet is caused by using the <li> tag. Remove it and you are good to go.

There is no need either in the  element. I don't know how much to delete from the code.

Remove the start tag: <li class="cat-' . $category->cat_ID . '">

Remove the end tag: </li>

I updated my question, in case someone has a simpler and cleaner code that is suitable for use, than the one I gave as an example

You would not need the <ul> and <li> tags, so those can be removed.  Also, since you are no longer concatenating them into the string, the $second_output variable can be updated with the $return_string variable instead.  Also, a couple minor tweaks in the snip below.
function categories_list_func( $atts ){
     if($categories = get_the_category()) {
        foreach($categories as $category) {
            $output .= $category->cat_name;
        }
        $return_string = trim($output);
      }

 return $return_string;

} // END Categories
add_shortcode( 'categories-list', 'categories_list_func' );


Thanks for your explanation and answer! exactly what I wanted :)
